# Class App\Http\Requests\TagStoreRequest does not exist

Tags: laravel

Hola estoy intentando guardar/Actualizar Pero cuando intento hacer eso ocurre un error.

```
Class App\Http\Requests\TagStoreRequest does not exist

Class App\Http\Requests\TagUpdateRequest does not exist
```

En este ejemplo Tengo esto:

en mi    TagStoreRequest

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class TagStoreRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' = 'required',
            'slug' = 'required|unique:tags,slug',
        ];
    }
}
```

Este es el TagUpdateRequest

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class TagUpdateRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {   
        
        return [
            'name' = 'required',
            'slug' = 'required|unique:tags,slug,'.$this->tag,
        ];
    }
}
```

El crear Este es mi formualrio

```html
@extends('layouts.app')


@section('content')
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
   <div class="panel panel-default">

    <div class="panel-heading">
     
     Crear Etiqueta
     
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body">
     {!! Form::open(['route'=>'tags.store'])!!}
      
      @include('admin.tags.partials.form')

   
     {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>

   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

Form Que  se incluye

```html
<div class="form-group">
  {{ Form::label('name','Nombre de la etiqueta')}}
  {{ Form::text('name',null,['class' => 'form-control','id' =>'name'])}}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  {{ Form::label('slug','url Amigable')}}
  {{ Form::text('slug',null,['class' => 'form-control','id' =>'slug'])}}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 {{ Form::submit('Guardar',['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-primary'])}}
</div>

@section('scripts')
<script src="{{ asset('vendor/stringToSlug/jquery.stringToSlug.min.js')}}"></script>
<script >
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#name, #slug").stringToSlug({
   callback:function(text){
    $("#slug").val(text);
   }
  });
 });
</script>


@endsection
```

De esta forma tengo mi Controller

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


//validaciones 
use App\Http\Requests\TagStoreRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\TagUpdateRequest;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

//modelo
use App\Tag;


class TagController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->middleware('auth');
    }


    public function index()
    {
    
        $tags = Tag::orderBy('id','DESC')
        ->paginate();

        return view('admin.tags.index',compact('tags'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        ///muestra el formulario
        return view('admin.tags.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(TagStoreRequest $request)
    {
        //Validar 

        //Guarda la información

        $tag= Tag::create($request->all());
        //despues de Guardar, Pueda Editar.

        return redirect()
         ->route('tags.edit',$tag->id)
        ->with('info','Etiqueta Creada con Exito');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //para ver en detalle una etiqueta

        $tag =Tag::find($id);

        return view('admin.tags.show',compact('tag'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
         $tag= Tag::find($id);

        return view('admin.tags.edit',compact('tag'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(TagUpdateRequest $request, $id)
    {   
        //validar 

        $tag = Tag::find($id);

        //Actualizamos Segun su ID
        $tag->fill($request->all())->save();

        return redirect()
         ->route('tags.edit',$tag->id)
        ->with('info','Etiqueta Actualizada con Exito');

    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //para eliminar 
        $tag = Tag::find($id)->delete();
        
        return back()->with('Info','Eliminado Correctamente');

    }
}
```

Así es como tengo mis archivos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Claramente la  es la clase  dice que no existe
pero según todo lo he hecho bien, más sin embargo pues no funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi ruta:

```
Route::resource('tags',        'Admin\TagController');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes un error bien definido en tus `FormRequest` tanto en `TagUpdateRequest` como en `TagStoreRequest`  el array de validaciones debe ser asociativo `clave => valor` , y lo que está haciendo es incorrecto ya que el símbolo correcto de asociación es `=>`  y no `=` , al tener errores como este Laravel no compila correctamente las clases y por lo cuál obtiene este resultado de *"Clase no existe"*

**TagStoreRequest**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required',
        'slug' => 'required|unique:tags,slug',
    ];
}
```

**TagUpdateRequest**

```
public function rules()
{   

    return [
        'name' => 'required',
        'slug' => 'required|unique:tags,slug,'.$this->tag,
    ];
}
```

Si luego de esto persiste con el error , otra opción sería utilizar el comando

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: Tienes toda la razón. Ya funciona!