# Laravel: Error en Form Request

Tags: laravel

Estoy comenzando a usar Form Request, cree la clase tal cual indica la documentación de Laravel con el comando:

```
php artisan make:request CreateProyectRequest
```

Pero al querer ingresar un nuevo registro en la tabla de mi base de datos, me esta presentando este error:

```
Class App\Http\Requests\CreateProyectRequest does not exist
```

Mi código en CreateProyectRequest es el siguiente:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CreateProyectRequest extends FormRequest
{

public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required',
        'url' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'title' = 'El proyecto necesita un título'
    ]
}
}
```

Y en el ProyectController es:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Proyect;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\CreateProyectRequest;

class ProyectController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
    return view('proyects.index', [
        'proyects' => Proyect::latest()->paginate()
    ]);
}

public function show(Proyect $proyect)
{        
    return view('proyects.show', [
        'proyect' => $proyect
    ]);
}

public function create()
{
    return view('proyects.create');
}

public function store(CreateProyectRequest $request)
{
    Proyect::create( $request->validated() );

    return redirect()->route('proyects.index');
}
}
```

Ustedes ven el error??? Por favor, ayudenme...

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Class App\Http\Requests\TagStoreRequest does not exist](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/162387/class-app-http-requests-tagstorerequest-does-not-exist)

Comment: igual y haciendo un dumpautoload

Comment: @Aprendiz el primero de los dos errores que citas no es un error... de hecho actualmente es considerado una buena práctica en PHP, y está permitido hace mucho tiempo.

Answer (score 3):

Acorde a la pregunta [Class App\Http\Requests\TagStoreRequest does not exist](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/162387/class-app-http-requests-tagstorerequest-does-not-exist) parece que esto puede ocurrir cuando tienes un error de sintaxis en tu clase de `Request`. El único que alcanzo a ver es la falta de `;` en el `return` de la función `messages` de tu clase `CreateProyectRequest`. Quizá corrigiéndolo pudieras avanzar.

Cabe recalcar que PHP acepta un trailing comma https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829581/why-do-php-array-examples-leave-a-trailing-comma en la declaración de arreglos.